# Android action bar and tabs

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I have implemented ActionBar in my app and I have 3 tabs (Fragments) inside the actionbar.

I want to show options (light blue colored bar in screenshot) with some buttons at the bottom of the screen.

Can someone guide me about how to implement this?

Thanks

Comment: That light blue colored bar, it again tab bar or you want to add it in on Menu button press?

Comment: it should appear when app is opened..Just like gmail app for android.

Comment: @RAD What wireframe software did you use to sketch the above work? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Ben: Balsamiq Mock up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to display the actionbar menu items at the bottom add to the activity element in the manifest file this attribute

```
android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

example:

```
<activity 
android:name=".HomeScreen"
...
...
android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
```

Comment: I tried this but the menu appears when i click on my options menu button on phone. I want my menu to appear always. May be my question is confusing between action bar and options menu. Are they same?

Comment: I figured out finally what when wrong. I did not use Show Actions = ifRoom while creating the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got your question. You can try a tab host for upper tabs and relative layout for the below bar where you can put your stuff.

Comment: according to new changes, it is recommended to use Fragments instead of TabHost. So I am using Fragments for tabs. Looks like there is not easy solution to this :(